# Using Quickbooks SDK: how should we import commissions?

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, qbfc

One of my developers is attempting to import commissions (related to payroll) from one our products via the QuickBooks SDK.

So far the only solution he's been able to come up with is to create a pay type with a pay rate per hour and convert the actual commission amount to an hour rate based on that. It's ugly and will very likely break.

He says that QuickBooks can do commissions manually, but that the API does not have the ability to do this. For example, it has `IPayrollItemNonWageQuery` and such, and it has `IPayrollItemWageAdd`, but no `IPayrollItemNonWageAdd`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payroll is one area that is locked down from the SDK.  You can't touch the payroll items or payroll checks.  You do have fairly good access to time sheets, so if there's something you can express in a timesheet that's legitimate, you can then crank the timesheets through payroll.  In other words your dev has probably come up with the least ugly hack to get this into payroll.  Of course you could pay commissions with expense checks, but if you're paying employees that's not a good option.

Comment: My dev says we do the expense checks right now, but our client doesn't want that. He tried the timesheet approach, but it requires a rather large pay rate, hours has a limit of 2 decimal places, and QuickBooks, he says, calculates overtime automatically. Thanks for the info.